# Solr query term matching

Tags: solr, schema

So I am relatively new to Solr and I have a query regarding its matching of a term and perhaps the syntax where I am going wrong..

lets say I have the following schema:

```
<field name="s_broker_name" type="search_text_type" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
...
<copyField source="broker_name" dest="s_broker_name"/>
...
    <fieldType name="search_text_type" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

if I index the value for broker_name as "Dylan, Bob" and my query syntax is s_broker_name:*Dylan, Bob* why wouldn't that find anything?

Is there a simple way I can strip out the comma  when handling the query?

thanks,

Comment: Are you really using leading _and_ trailing wildcards (e.g. q=*sample*)? Try to avoid it, [read here](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Wildcard-searches-with-leading-and-ending-wildcard-td3992086.html).

Answer (score 0):

Very handy feature of Solr is its analysis page. Just choose this field and type what you have in a query and see how the analysis chain goes.

Two things:

1. the , will be stripped by StandardTokenizerFactory
2. to strip * use StandardFilterFactory after StandardTokenizerFactory or don't type those
3. in order to get the search against the same field, make sure to use parentheses: s_broker_name:(Dylan, Bob). Otherwise Bob will be searched against what is configured as your default field in solrconfig.xml.